# Excel formula to remove all alphanumeric char from string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

Why does this not work as expected?

```
=SUBSTITUTE("HEL3LO";CHAR(SEQUENCE(26;1;65));"")
```

I would expect and result of `3`, I get and array of inconsistent results.

Any suggestions?

With VBA it not a problem, but I prefer to find the formula, to avoid sharing workbooks with macros.

Comment: This should work `=TEXTSPLIT("HEL3LO";CHAR(SEQUENCE(26;;65));;1)` But your OP says to remove all alphanumeric characters and your expecting the result to be `3` so are you looking to remove all letters?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is more than one numeric character?

Comment: Just a quick headsup. Your title is suggesting you want to delete all **alphanumeric** characters. You do know that this would include all numbers too right? You wish to remove all except numbers perhaps? What about a string like `H3110_W0R1D!`

Comment: thx for the helps, it gave me a new idea, it looks I managed to get it done:
=LET(c;A1;s;SEQUENCE(LEN(c));x;SEQUENCE(255;;1);CONCAT(CHAR(FILTER(CODE(MID(c;s;1));NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(CODE(MID(c;s;1));FILTER(x;NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x;SEQUENCE(10;;48))))))))))))
this will extract any number from a string in cell A1
a little complicated and i think amazing excel can do it. however putting an array (A1:A5) instead of one cell (A1) is a step too much. 
on 'H3110_W0R1D!' it works. with this, i will be able to take out the numbers too.

Comment: this is the one for taking out ALL numbers and leaving all others:
=LET(z;"H3110_W0R1D!";w;MID(z;SEQUENCE(LEN(z));1);f;LET(c;z;s;SEQUENCE(LEN(c));x;SEQUENCE(255;;1);CONCAT(CHAR(FILTER(CODE(MID(c;s;1));NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(CODE(MID(c;s;1));FILTER(x;NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x;SEQUENCE(10;;48))))))))))));CONCAT(FILTER(w;NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(w;MID(f;SEQUENCE(LEN(f));1)))))))
did not get simpler, but it works.

Comment: How is this working with semicolons separating the parameters in the formula?  That doesn't work when I try it...

Comment: I don't think a dynamic array is the right solution here.  Why?  You're looking for a single result, not multiple results.

Comment: @TrippKinetics it seems the OP has a different local regional setting than you have, if you replace semi-colon with commas for your case, it might work.

Answer (score 3):

As per my comments above, if you need to get the output for only the numeric `3` then use the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTSPLIT("HEL3LO",CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),,1)
```

---

Edit: Inspiration from here **[link](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/jvdv-073152276_some-formulae-to-clean-strings-for-reference-activity-7094666665736429568-VKL9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)** by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) Sir**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(TOROW(MID(B1,SEQUENCE(LEN(B1)),1)/1,3))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(B2,TAKE(SORT(CHAR(SEQUENCE(95,,32))),43),,1))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C3</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(B3,SEQUENCE(10)-1,,1))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C4</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(B4,DROP(SORT(CHAR(SEQUENCE(95,,32))),43),,1))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C5</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(B5,TAKE(SORT(CHAR(SEQUENCE(95,,32))),33),,1))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C6</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(B6,DROP(SORT(CHAR(SEQUENCE(95,,32))),33),,1))
```

---

Comment: Don't forget to [`CONCAT()`](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/jvdv-073152276_some-formulae-to-clean-strings-for-reference-activity-7094666665736429568-VKL9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop) the whole thing back together. I suppose OP's data could potentially contain multiple digits.

Comment: I agree with you @JvdV Sir, I have asked questions also to OP, waiting for their response. Surely will update that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE`, but as follows to emulate a recursion via `REDUCE`, one of the [LAMBDA Helper functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648):

```
=REDUCE("HEL3LO", CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,1,65)),LAMBDA(ac,x,SUBSTITUTE(ac,x,"")))
```

**Note**: By the way, to remove capital letters you can simple use: `CHAR(ROW(65:90))` instead of: `SEQUENCE(26,1,65))`. If you want to include lower letters too you can use: `VSTACK(ROW(65:90), ROW(97:122))`. In a similar way you can keep adding additional set of characters.

[image: output]

You can encapsulate it in a user `LAMBDA` function as follows:

```
CLEAN_STR=LAMBDA(txt,arr,REDUCE(txt,arr,LAMBDA(ac,x,SUBSTITUTE(ac,x,""))))
```

Save it in the *Name Manager* and then use it as follows:

```
=CLEAN_STR("HEL3LO",CHAR(ROW(65:90)))
```

Now you can use it for different purposes.

Comment: Excellent.  I can see further use for this kind of thing, using translation tables to process data similarly to regex tools.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of reasons why it doesn't work, but this formula has none of those reasons:

```
=LET(
    txt, B2,
    remove, VSTACK(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 65)), CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 97))),
    REDUCE(
        txt,
        remove,
        LAMBDA(t,r, SUBSTITUTE(t, r, ""))
    )
)
```

[image]